# How to configure React Native Linking?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am using deep linking for handling notifications in my app. For remote notifications I use `React Native Firebase` and for local notifications I use `react-native-push-notification`. I am handling background and quit state notifications with react-navigation's deep linking system, but for foreground notifications I use react-native's Linking and this is where the problem is. `Linking.canOpenUrl` returns supported but `Linking.openUrl` does nothing. I already added `LSApplicationQueriesScheme` key to my `info.plist` and added my prefix to it.

this is for foreground handling =>

```
const onOpenNotification = async (data) => {
    const messagesObj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('messages')
    const messages = JSON.parse(messagesObj)
    const notificationData  = messages[data.id]

    Linking.canOpenURL(notificationData.link).then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
            console.log("supported!")
            Linking.openURL(notificationData.link)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Cannot open! ")
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

this is for background and quit state handling =>

```
export const notificationLinking = {
prefixes: ['rateet://app'],
config,
async getInitialUrl(){
    // Check if app was opened from a deep link
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    if (url != null) {
        return url;
    }

    // Check if there is an initial firebase notification
    const message = await messaging().getInitialNotification();


    // Get the `url` property from the notification which corresponds to a screen
    // This property needs to be set on the notification payload when sending it
    return message?.data.link;
},
subscribe(listener){
    const onReceiveURL = (url) => listener(url);

    // Listen to incoming links from deep linking
    Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

    // Listen to firebase push notifications
    const unsubscribeNotification = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(
        (message) => {
        const url = message.data.link;

        if (url) {
            // Any custom logic to check whether the URL needs to be handled
            //...

            // Call the listener to let React Navigation handle the URL
            listener(url);
        }
        }
    );


    return () => {
        // Clean up the event listeners
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
        unsubscribeNotification();
    }
}
```

}